# Amazon Product API - Promo Codes

Tags: amazon-product-api, amazon-product-advertising-api

After being approved for Amazon Affiliate Program, you get access to a page called Amazon Promo Codes. Is it possible to get these promo codes using PA API?

I have checked their API and played around with it using Scratchpad but I could not find any placeholder where coupon code would be present.

What I have tried so far

- Tried searching with ASIN for which promo codes were available but after search for it I could not find any codes in the API response
- Tried to search with "Amazon Promo Code" using the search API but again no coupons were found.